# Find matching values in SQL based on multiple variables

Tags: sql-server

UPDATED! I want to find rows in table_20220121 where two variables matches the table_20220121_b. Also, there could be several matches in table_20220121, but I only want the one with the biggest [Time since 1970]-value, that is, I want the **output to be the row with number 88 and 1391 in table_20220121**. Thanks!

```
drop table table_20220121
drop table table_20220121_b
drop table table_output

CREATE TABLE table_20220121
(
number  float,
IP   nvarchar(100),
[Time since 1970]   float,
[Timestamp]   nvarchar(100),
[Scroll Depth Threshold] float 
);
INSERT INTO table_20220121
VALUES
(84,'999.999.99.111',1635332371761,'2021-10-27T12:59:31.761+02:00',0.7),
(85,'999.999.99.111',1635332377747,'2021-10-27T12:59:37.747+02:00',0.7),
(86,'999.999.99.111',1635332387744,'2021-10-27T12:59:47.744+02:00',0.7),
(87,'999.999.99.111',1635332388600,'2021-10-27T12:59:48.600+02:00',0.8),
(88,'999.999.99.111',1635332397761,'2021-10-27T12:59:57.761+02:00',0.8),
(1387,'999.999.99.999',1640983016936,'2021-12-31T21:36:56.936+01:00',0.4),
(1388,'999.999.99.999',1640983030370,'2021-12-31T21:37:10.370+01:00',0.5),
(1389,'999.999.99.999',1640983055463,'2021-12-31T21:37:35.463+01:00',0.5),
(1390,'999.999.99.999',1640983100401,'2021-12-31T21:38:20.401+01:00',0.6),
(1391,'999.999.99.999',1640983115461,'2021-12-31T21:38:35.460+01:00',0.6)
;

CREATE TABLE table_20220121_b
(
IP   nvarchar(100),
[Scroll Depth Threshold] float 
);
INSERT INTO table_20220121_b
VALUES
('999.999.99.999',0.6),
('999.999.99.111',0.8)
;

select * from table_20220121;
select * from table_20220121_b;
go
```

Actually, this below is the **ANSWER** to my question. I have provided it here in the question section just for clarity:

```
with matches as (
   select *, Row_Number() over(partition by ip order by [Time since 1970] desc) rn
   from table_20220121 ta 
   where exists (
       select * from table_20220121_b tb 
       where ta.ip=tb.ip 
         and ta.[Scroll Depth Threshold] = tb.[Scroll Depth Threshold]
   )
)
select number, ip, [Time since 1970], Timestamp, [Scroll Depth Threshold]
/* into table_output */
from matches
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Do not post answers in questions. You are welcome to answer your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you have tried to use is not supported by SQL Server (and you're using 'string literals' so if the syntax *were* supported, it would always return true); however you can just join the tables using multiple criteria and take the `top n`

```
select top(1) ta.*
/* into table_output */
from table_20220121 ta 
join table_20220121_b tb on ta.ip = tb.ip 
  and ta.[Scroll Depth Threshold] = tb.[Scroll Depth Threshold]
order by [Time since 1970] desc;
```

Alternatively you can join and filter for multiple rows using *row_number* to filter for the maximum value per group:

```
with matches as (
    select *, Row_Number() over(partition by ip order by [Time since 1970] desc) rn
    from table_20220121 ta 
    where exists (
        select * from table_20220121_b tb 
        where ta.ip=tb.ip 
          and ta.[Scroll Depth Threshold] = tb.[Scroll Depth Threshold]
    )
)
select number, ip, [Time since 1970], Timestamp, [Scroll Depth Threshold]
/* into table_output */
from matches
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Your answer indeed solves my question, but I need a more general answer. For example, the table table_20220121_b can have many rows, so it does not work when I test on my big table.

Comment: Ok I have updated above with an alternative method - your question was quite explicit about finding the *one* row, but assuming (you haven't made it clear) you want to do this for multiple IP addresses, you can use *row number* to partition by IP groups.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated by question now. Your code provided me with my desired output.